# my login page code is not working and ideas how to fix it? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a login and sign up page in python but i need a bit of help with the login part.

my code for the login page is:

```
import time as t
f_content = open("info.txt",'r').read()
while True:
    username = input("Username:")
    password = input("Password:")
    infos = [username,password]
    for user in f_content:
        user_info = user.split(":")
        if user_info == infos:
            found = True
            print("Successfully logged in!")
            #some code

    if not found:
        print("User was not found!\nWait 20 seconds to reset")
        t.sleep(20)
```

And i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Man\Downloads\python login\login.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not found:
NameError: name 'found' is not defined
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define 'found' before your loop, best as 'False'.

```
import time as t
f_content = open("info.txt",'r').read()
while True:
    username = input("Username:")
    password = input("Password:")
    infos = [username,password]
    found = False
    for user in f_content:
        user_info = user.split(":")
        if user_info == infos:
            found = True
            print("Successfully logged in!")
            #some code

    if not found:
        print("User was not found!\nWait 20 seconds to reset")
        t.sleep(20)
```